# Column wrongly tagged as int when is num

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, readr

I have generated a dataframe that contains 9829 observations of 37 variables and saved it with write_csv.

When loading this dataframe in shiny with read_csv one column is tagged as int when its values are floating numbers, this causes all floating values in this column to be set to NA.

After close investigation it appears that the problem is that the first ~4000 observations in that column are 0 with no digits which seems to be a problem with the reading function.

A quick fix for the issue has been to sort the dataframe in descending order with the column that causes the problem before saving. But this is not a valid solution as I may have more than one column with this issue in the future.

**Question:** Is there a way to set write_csv to write all items in floating columns with 2 digits precision? Or to fix the issue automatically

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
library(tidyverse)

col1 <- c(c(0:5000), c(2.1,3.5))
df <- data.frame(col1)

write_csv(df, "./data_out/test/wrong_dataType_issue.csv")
df_read <- read_csv("./data_out/test/wrong_dataType_issue.csv")
summary(df_read)

 col1     
 Min.   :   0  
 1st Qu.:1250  
 Median :2500  
 Mean   :2500  
 3rd Qu.:3749  
 Max.   :4999  
 NA's   :7
```

Comment: Can you show us some code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Set the types in `read_csv` with `col_types = col(some_variable = col_double())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `read_csv()` looks at the first 1,000 rows of data. I suggest [this chapter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-import.html) of *R for Data Science* for background. It's possible for the function to guess incorrectly. For example, I once had a dataset where the column `gender` was marked as logical because the first 1,000 rows were all female, and the function interpreted "F" to mean "FALSE". There's the right way to fix this problem and the quick way.

**The quick way**

`read_csv()` has an argument called `guess_max` that sets how many rows to explore. You could use something like this as a hacky way to fix the problem...

```
read_csv("my_data.csv", guess_max = 9829)
```

That forces the `read_csv()` function to look at every value in your dataset before guessing the column types. It'll fix your problem but it might cause more trouble in the future, especially if embedded in a Shiny app where the underlying data might change.

**The right way**

`read_csv()` makes it easy to explicitly define the data types of all your columns. If you want to make sure that column `age` is always read as numeric, use something like the following...

```
read_csv("my_data.csv", col_types = cols(age = col_double())
```

Comment: Thank you. About the quick way: How shiny might change thge data? What other issues may I run into?

Comment: @Treizh If the data file ever has a different number of rows in the future, it'll have problems. Will the Shiny app always be pulling the same data from the same csv file? If so, you might want to format the data and then save it using the feather package. That will load faster and always use the correct column types.